# Should I use browser field in package.json when authoring a library that exports a function to the global object?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I'm developing a javascript library and I have set 'browser', 'module' and 'main' fields in package.json, each one with a different entry point.

```
// package.json
"main": "./dist/umd/index.js",
"browser": "./dist/browser/index.js",
"module": "./dist/esm/index.js",
...
```

In the browser bundle, the library is exposed to window as a global function so it can be used with a script tag like:

```js
const x = 42;
const msg = match(x)
  .caseLessThan(0, "Negative values not allowed")
  .default(_ => `${_} items selected`);
           
alert(msg);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/x-match-expression/dist/browser/index.js"></script>
```

The issue is that when trying to use the library in another project with webpack, it uses 'browser' entry point by default and the function is not resolved correctly, getting an undefine error at runtime.

```
import {match} from "x-match-expression";
const x = 42;
const msg = match(x) // <--- match is undefined at runtime with default webpack settings
  .caseLessThan(0, "Negative values not allowed")
  .default(_ => `${_} items selected`);
```

I know the resolve fields can be set in webpack by setting resolve.mainFields but this would be counterintuitive for users of my library so I had to remove the 'browser' entry point in package.json but I don't know if is there a better approach.

Should I be using 'browser' field in package.json? Or should I just provide the browser bundle but without referencing it in the package.json to be used with a script tag?